# Switch value of elements on some positions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array X of size N, filled with 0 and 1.

I generate a sample S of size M

I want to revert the elements of X on each position from sample S.

I want to ask whether this is possible without using loops, but using some atomic operation from the numpy mask module.

I want to any type of loop like

```
for i in sample:
    X[i] = 1-X[i]
```

and replace it with a single call in pylab.

Possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `X[sample] = 1 - X[sample]`.

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
>>> sample = [1,2,3]
>>> X[sample]
array([1, 0, 1])
>>> X[sample] = 1 - X[sample]
>>> X
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Comment: really beautiful. I remembered now this syntax, that I had forgotten. many thanks.